# Plotly Format Axis Date

Tags: javascript, date-formatting, plotly.js

In the following code, if I choose `scatter3d` instead of `scatter`, all parameter `tickformat` and `title` inside `xaxis` are **completely ignored**, and it is impossible to format anything under any axis.

Any suggetion would be appreciated.

**Failing 3D Plot with outrageous date format**

[image]

**Working Plot with proper HH:MM:SS Format**

[image]

```
function setup_plot(){
    type='scatter';
    var x=[],x0=new Date();
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        x[i]=new Date();
        x[i].setTime(x0.getTime()+i*12*3600000);
    }
    var trace = [
        {
            type: type,
            mode: 'lines',
            x: x,
            y: [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],
            z: [2.6,1.2,6.3,4.8,4.7]
        },
        {
            type: type,
            mode: 'lines',
            x: x,
            y: [2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,.0],
            z: [3.1,2.6,4.8,3.8,1.7]
        }
    ];
    var layout = {
        title: "Failing Plot",
        xaxis:{
            title:'Dates',
            tickformat: '%H:%M:%S',
            tickformatstops: [
                {
                dtickrange: [1000,60000],
                value: '%H:%M:%S'
                },
                {
                dtickrange: [60000,3600000],
                value: '%H:%M:%S'
                },
                {
                dtickrange: [3600000,86400000],
                value: '%H:%M:%S'
                },
                {
                dtickrange: [86400000,604800000],
                value: '%d'
                }
            ]
        }
    };
    Plotly.newPlot('plot',trace,layout);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3d charts, axis layouts have to be provided within a scene, so

```
const layout = {
  scene: {
    xaxis: {
      title: 'Dates',
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

See https://plotly.com/javascript/3d-axes/